# How to redirect user when user returns to application

Tags: java, android, android-activity, return

I have 2 activity. I left the app while in `Activity2` when I returned with the hard key on the left, it was still in `Activity2` but when I got to the app at home it turned back to `Activity1` so how can it return to `Activity2` in both ways?

Thank !

Comment: If the app is still running on background it should still open `Activity 2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always see activity2 upon opening the app, you can set it as your main activity in the manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourActivityName"
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But if you don't turn off the app completely (do not swipe it away or shut it off) then the app will always return to the last activity where you left since the app is still running in the background